# matlab: how can i create simpe objects and later print them well formatted

Tags: matlab

I am new to matlab,

I was working in python previously. In python we can create objects using

```py
var1 = 10
var2 = 10
a = {
    "prop1": var1,
    "prop2": var2
}

#and the most important thing is i can print it as a formatted obj using

print(json.dumps(a,indent=4,default=str))
```

How can we do such thing in matlab

Comment: There is a [jsonencode](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/jsonencode.html), but it lacks pretty printing options.

Comment: Look for `struct` in the docs. And while you’re at it, read the introductory tutorial. MATLAB has the best docs in the business, you really need to use them!

Comment: @rahnema: Is there any alternative for pretty printing json to a file in matlab

Comment: @Cris Luengo: Never used structs, i will check it

Comment: I googled `matlab+pretty+print+json` and found very good results including: [mps.json.encode](https://www.mathworks.com/help/compiler_sdk/mps_dev_test/mps.json.encode.html).

Comment: I will check it. it has pretty printing